# Reducing the Size of the TEXshop Console

Tags: mac, texshop, console

I'm new to using LaTeX and TeXshop. I'm not sure what I did or how this happened, but  the TeX console window is taking up almost the whole width of the of my screen.

[image]

This happened recently, it used to look like this (this screenshot is from my laptop).
[image]

I don't know what to do to minimize the window.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. This is very strange indeed, because the TeXShop console is fixed width; only its height is changeable. Does the size persist if you quit out of TeXShop and restart it?  What version of TeXShop are you using, and what version of MacOS? It looks like you're using a different theme on your laptop. Does anything change if you change the Theme from within TeXShop?

Comment: @AlanMunn Hi, I think I figured it out. In TeXShop Preferences, under Console, under Console Resize, "Vertical Resize Only" was selected. I am not sure how this happened but when I selected "Arbitrary Resize" I was able to decrease the size of the console. Thank you for your help and, yes, my iMac is in dark mode whereas my laptop is in normal or light mode.

Comment: I had no idea that that preference existed, but it is also checked in my TeXShop which is why I thought that the window couldn't be changed horizontally. Since this is a question that might well help others, you can add an answer yourself explaining the preference.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you for letting me know, because I wasn't sure if I was allowed to answer my own question. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the issue was, the Console Resize preferences were set to "Vertical Resize Only". Which was preventing me from decreasing the width of the console window. If you're having the same problem I was having, heres how you fix it:

Go to TeXShop Preferences, Console, Console Resize, select "Arbitrary Resize" and press OK.[image]